# Aurora-mysql cross-region replicas fail with views/procedures/functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, amazon-rds

**UPDATE 2** - AWS released Aurora-mysql platform update 1.19.1 which addresses this and other issues. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.1191.html

**UPDATE** - AWS Support confirmed this is a known issue with Aurora mysql 1.x platform cross-region replicas. The workaround is to call `mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;` on the replica after making view/procedure/function changes on the master until the replica is un-stuck and then make those view/procedure/function changes on the replica manually

When I set up cross-region replication with Amazon Aurora-mysql (1.x platform, 5.6 engine version), it works fine until I create a view, function, or procedure in the master and then the slave encounters an error and replication ceases until I call `CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;`. The error is:

```
[ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation' on query. Default database: 'mydatabasename'. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`myusername`@`%` PROCEDURE `MyProcedureName`... (SNIP SQL HERE)'
2019-05-09 02:29:10 8118 [Warning] Slave: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation Error_code: 1227
2019-05-09 02:29:10 8118 [Warning] Slave: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation Error_code: 1227
2019-05-09 02:29:10 8118 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin-changelog.000016' position 24293051
```

This is because the slave runs replication as `rdsrepladmin` user, but when I create my procedure on master, I'm logged in as `myusername`. I can't set DEFINER to anything other than that because Aurora won't let me have SUPER privilege (which you need in order to create a view/procedure/function as a different user).

I also don't seem to be able to ignore views/procedures/functions as part of the replications.

Is there any way around this besides calling `CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;` on the slave every time I have to touch a view/proc/function?

Comment: Check the value of `log_bin_trust_function_creators` in the parameter group.  It almost certainly needs to be enabled.

Comment: Thank you!  I do have `log_bin_trust_function_creators ` set to (1) on both the master and the slave.

Comment: Having the same issue and looks like the problem is happening if your aurora version is under 1.19.2. They have fixed a bug which can be related in that aurora version.